# Using Gurobi in Python and adding variables

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, gurobi

I am trying to write my first Gurobi optimization code and this is where I am stuck with:

I have the following dictionary for my first subscript:

input `for k in range(1,11):
          i[k] = int(k)
      print i`

output `{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10}`

And, I have the following dictionaries for my second subscript:

```
c_il = {1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 4, 5: 3, 6: 4, 7: 3, 8: 2, 9: 1, 10: 4}

c_iu = {1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 5, 5: 4, 6: 5, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 2, 10: 5}
```

I am trying to create variables as following:

```
x = m.addVars(i, c_il, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x")
x = m.addVars(i, c_iu, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x")
```

Apparently, it is not giving what I am looking for. What I am looking for is `x_(i),(c_il)` and `x_(i),(c_iu)`; ignore parenthesis.

More clearly, the following is what I am trying to obtain by using dicts `i`, `c_il`, and `c_iu`:

```
{1: <gurobi.Var x[1,2]>,
 2: <gurobi.Var x[2,1]>,
 3: <gurobi.Var x[3,1]>,
 4: <gurobi.Var x[4,5]>,
 5: <gurobi.Var x[5,3]>,
 6: <gurobi.Var x[6,4]>,
 7: <gurobi.Var x[7,3]>,
 8: <gurobi.Var x[8,2]>,
 9: <gurobi.Var x[9,1]>,
 10: <gurobi.Var x[10,4]>,
 11: <gurobi.Var x[1,3]>,
 12: <gurobi.Var x[2,2]>,
 13: <gurobi.Var x[3,2]>,
 14: <gurobi.Var x[4,5]>,
 15: <gurobi.Var x[5,4]>,
 16: <gurobi.Var x[6,5]>,
 17: <gurobi.Var x[7,4]>,
 18: <gurobi.Var x[8,3]>,
 19: <gurobi.Var x[9,2]>,
 20: <gurobi.Var x[10,5]>}
```

Since I am using dictionaries everywhere, I want to keep it consistent by continuing to use dictionaries so that I can do multiplications and additions with my parameters which are all in dictionaries. Is there any way to create these variables with m.addVars or m.addVar?

Thanks!

Edit: Modified to make it more clear.

Comment: This should be very simple. I just basically need to convert `c_il` and `c_iu` into gurobi variables as `1: <gurobi.Var x[12]>` and so on... Even another Gurobi Optimization beginner can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few years of experience, I can easily write the below as an answer. Since the past myself was concerned with keeping the dictionaries as is (I highly criticize and question...), a quick solution is as follows.

```
x = {}
for (i,j) in c_il.items():
    x[i,j] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x%s"%str([i,j]))
for (i,j) in c_iu.items():
    x[i,j] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x%s"%str([i,j]))
```

Alternatively,

```
x = {(i,j): m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x%s"%str([i,j])) 
         for (i,j) in c_il.items()}
for (i,j) in c_iu.items():
    x[i,j] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x%s"%str([i,j]))
```

One liner alternative:

```
x = {(i,j): m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x%s"%str([i,j])) 
     for (i,j) in [(k,l) for (k,l) in c_il.items()] + [(k,l) for (k,l) in c_iu.items()]}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this! really appreciate it. I just posted a question on Gurobi: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4405484241937-How-to-add-constraints-for-a-14-day-cycle-of-production-and-delivery?page=1#community_comment_4405556762257
wonder whether you have any suggestion for me since you seems to have a vast knowledge by now :) Thank you in advance

Comment: Why create x using a dictionary when Model.addVars does that for you?

Comment: Greg, I have no relation to the original poster, but that is how he wanted J. I agree that addVars is more convenient and faster in many cases. I guess, the posted way is easier for beginners to understand.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to create 10 variables that are indexed by something.  The best way to do this is to create the two indexes as lists.  If you want x[12], x[21], then write:

```
from gurobipy import *

m = Model()
il = [ 12, 21, 31, 44, 53, 64, 73, 82, 91, 104 ]
x = m.addVars(il, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x")
```

And if you want to write x[1,2], x[2,1], then write:

```
from gurobipy import *

m = Model()
il = [ (1,2), (2,1), (3,1), (4,4), (5,3), (6,4), (7,3), (8,2), (9,1), (10,4) ]
x = m.addVars(il, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x")
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your help. I realized that for consistency, I need to use dictionaries rather than tuplelists. Assume, my `i` is also a dictionary as following: `{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10}`. Any way to do the same thing for dictionaries like setting `il` as a dictionary? If yes, how should I combine `i` and `ci_l` in one `il` dictionary to put it in the `m.addVars` function? My purpose is not to type all numbers one by one. There are more than 10 values in `i`. I am just trying to understand the logic with the small sample.

Comment: Nevermind, I got how to do it! Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @tcokyasar can you share your answer? I have the same problem..

Comment: Here it is @Nellyv. Good luck!

Comment: @tcokyasar thank you so so much for this! really appreciate it. I just posted a question on Gurobi: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4405484241937-How-to-add-constraints-for-a-14-day-cycle-of-production-and-delivery?page=1#community_comment_4405556762257
wonder whether you have any suggestions for me since you seem to have a vast knowledge by now :) Thank you in advance